# Podcast Software for Mobile

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

Im looking for program that works on my windows mobile that i can listen to pod casts with im looking for the following.

- Ability to download pod casts from
  RSS feeds
- Ability
  ( You would think this is a not
  something i would have to ask for,
  but the pod cast players i found did
  not support pasting in the url to the
  rss feed)
- Bonus: Ability to share the
  podcast list with my windows computer

Limits
Cannot be itunes.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Pocket Podcasts](http://pocketpodcasts.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

I use [Juice](http://juicereceiver.sourceforge.net/) for my windows machine, which doesn't specifically say it can be used for windows mobile, but since it's open source, perhaps you can get it to work.  Their web page also has links to several related sites, of which, [podnova](http://www.podnova.com/), might fit your needs.  They specifically say:

> Tired of synching your podcasts
>   through iTunes?
>
> Let us stream all your favorite
>   content right into your pocket.
>
> PodNova Mobile m.podnova.com

Answer (score 1):

[BeyondPodcast](http://beyondpodcast.mobi/)

Watch the demo, it is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

[BeyondPod](http://www.codeplex.com/beyondpod) is awesome. Manage it all from your phone.